# Convert Pdf to multi images (png,jpg)

Tags: graphics

I read link: https://www.overleaf.com/blog/613-tip-of-the-week-how-to-convert-typeset-pdf-pages-into-raster-image-formats

i use Texmarker 5.0.3
Can i convert main.pdf to multi images (each page = one image)?

Example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]

ABC DEF

\end{tcolorbox}

\blindtext

\newpage
\clearpage
\blindtext

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]

XXX YYY

\end{tcolorbox}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the (complete) TeXLive distribution there is an interesting utility called `pdftoppm` that can convert PDF to PNG whith some options (e.g., on my Windows machine `C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\pdftoppm.exe`). The undeniable advantage is that there is no need to install anything.

Running `cmd` with `pdftoppm -help`, you get the following output that informs how the utility works:

[image]

Therefore, it suffices to write, e.g.,

`C:\path\to\my\PDFfile pdftoppm -f 1 -l 2 -r 300 -png Name_Of_My.pdf My_Images`

to convert your two pages PDF-output generated by LaTeX (`Name_Of_My.pdf`) to separate image files `My_Images-1.png` and `My_Images-2.png`, where the prefix name (`My_Images`) of generated PNG files comes from the last part of the command line above.

The PNG output from your MWE above follows...

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly, the PDF->image step is not done by LaTeX, but by an external call to `convert` (part of [ImageMagick suite](https://imagemagick.org/index.php)). So maybe this is off-topic, but...

Basically, once you have installed it, you should be able to use this command (at least in Linux, I think it will be the same in other OSs):

```
 convert -density 300 -background white -alpha remove -alpha off pdf-file.pdf page.png
```

and you'll have your pages at 300 dpi, named `page-0.png`, `page-1.png` and so on.

Notice that the latest `convert` can have problems. Be sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453 and https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/396 and then if you have errors edit your `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` to say:

```xml
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="4GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="4GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="128KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="128KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="1.28GP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="8GiB"/>

  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="EPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="XPS" />
```

In the original files, the `rights` were `none` and the limits much lower, which will hinder execution for a medium-size PDF file.

Comment: Just a comment for windows users: If I remember correctly, there was some conflict with a build in windows tool of the same name, so `convert` uses a different name on windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/38163913/2777074

Answer (score 0):

I find `pdftoppm` (poppler tool) to be much more efficient than imagemagick/convert, with a better quality (when I set a too high quality with convert, it crashes). For instance, you can do:

```
pdftoppm -jpeg -r 300 -scale-to-x 1920 -scale-to-y 1080 yourfile.pdf output-prefix
```

and it will create many images like `output-prefix-01.jpg`, `output-prefix-02.jpg`… (the number of 0 is determined depending on the number of files)