# Convert PDF to PDF of images?

Tags: pdf, copy-paste

I have recently written a PDF with LaTeX. That means that you are able to copy and parse the PDF text.

Out of pure interest: How is it possible to convert all pages to images (collected in a big PDF), such that automatical text extraction does not work without some time and expertise?
In other words: For a human user, the resulting PDF file should look unchanged and should be able to be printed onto A4 without visible loss, but text extraction (not considereing OCR) should yield not more than a few words.

I know [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503388/convert-pdf-to-multi-images-png-jpg) question, but the result is not one PDF file consisting of multiple images and I fear visible quality loss when doing too many conversion intersteps.

Comment: you can use image magic to convert to a sequence of pngs then collect them back up but you may find it has no actual use even free OCR tools such as google docs are pretty good these days and you may find that extracting the text from images is really a lot easier than you think.

Comment: the details of tools for obscuring a pdf file are probably mostly off topic here though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to produce a PDF with un-copyable text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-pdf-with-un-copyable-text)