# TeX or LaTeX file with a hidden pasword

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

This question is inspired by this one: [Convert PDF to PDF of images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628419/convert-pdf-to-pdf-of-images)

As the author does have the code, creating a LaTeX version that is difficult to decrypt seems to be a good solution. Certainly, it is easy to block the compilation as in The TeXbook:

```
\loop\iftrue
  \errmessage{This manual is copyrighted and should not be TeXed}\repeat
\pausing1 \input manmac
\ifproofmode\message{Proof mode is on!}\pausing1\fi
```

but it is easy to omit. One can, using `\immediate\write` and `\immediate\read` require a password to compile, but it is also visible in the code.

However, in this thread, [How can we draw a Christmas tree with decorations, using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz) David Carlisle gave a beautiful example of a pseudo-encrypted code.

How can we create such a code?

Comment: The engines support getting md5 hashes from files, you could use that for your password approach without storing your password in the file. But still, if I have access to the code I can circumvent whatever you use (and yes, even if you obfuscate your code as David often does, then it just takes a bit longer).

Comment: @Skillmon Certainly, my idea is useless against advanced TeX users. But the initial question was also a request to make harder the extraction of a text.

Comment: ... I'd definitely not encourage doing this. – Obviously, by doing the same way how normal DRM works in machine code/assembly – embed it into the source code, and make the whole thing *so large* that nobody have the effort to step through the code.

Comment: Actually, just implement AES-256 encryption in TeX, then dynamically decrypt the file with the provided password... at this stage just compress it with 7-zip.

Comment: You could as well (after implementing AES-256 in TeX) dump that into a format and only distribute the encrypted TeX file along the `cryptopdflatex` format and the password hash (which could be placed at the start of your encrypted file). Be aware that this way LaTeX will probably need a bit of time to run, and you wouldn't want to create any (unencrypted) temporary files as that would be an obvious security risk! I begin to really like this idea :)